# Carbon Fibre Bike Re spray

Tags: carbon, paint

I have a carbon fibre bike that i am looking to get re sprayed I have found a powder coating company near me [Profin](https://profingroup.co.uk) can you actually paint fibre or will it need to be wet sprayed??

Answer (score 2):

> Powder coating is a method of applying powder to a conductive substrate by electrically charging powder particles to deposit on substrates oppositely charged when influenced by a direct current.

From the website you linked.

Carbon fibre is generally not considered conductive for this purpose and will need to be wet sprayed.

It looks like they offer all the finishing services so perhaps you can still use the same company.

Comment: Powder coating usually also needs to be baked on. Not sure how that would impact the bonds in the CF.